# Transposing Many dates in a new Column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to transpose this sheet with pandas, but so far no deal:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ULg4Yi8NFYhgy-k9TO5qUN9-IBD4WWM8wHh9Ql96wx0/edit?usp=sharing

**My goal is getting the columns which are dates and fill out into a column called Date, and obviously distribute the values**

I even tried to pivot but I think it wouldn't work like that:

```
columns = result.columns.values    

import datetime as dt
from dateutil.parser import parse

def is_date_valid(this_date):
    try:
        parse(this_date).date()
    except ValueError:
        return False
    else:
        return True

for row in columns:
    # Here I am just checking if the column is a date
    if is_date_valid(row):
        df_ = result.pivot(index='Country/Region', columns='Date', values=row)
```

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated

Comment: I like`datetime.strptime`for formatting strings to dates. `from datetime import datetime`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're roughly looking for?

```py
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ULg4Yi8NFYhgy-k9TO5qUN9-IBD4WWM8wHh9Ql96wx0/export?format=csv&gid=1757633010'

df = pd.read_csv(url)

df = df.transpose()

print(df)
```

---

Result:

```
                    0      1          2        3         4                 5                6     ...       1418         1419       1420            1421       1422         1423                   1424
Province/State       NaN    NaN        NaN      NaN       NaN  British Columbia  New South Wales  ...        NaN          NaN         US      Montserrat        NaN          NaN                    NaN
1/22/20                0      0          0        0         0                 0                0  ...          0            0          0               0          0            0                      0
1/23/20                0      0          0        0         0                 0                0  ...          0            0          0               0          0            0                      0
1/24/20                0      0          0        0         0                 0                0  ...          0            0          0               0          0            0                      0
1/25/20                0      0          0        0         0                 0                0  ...          0            0          0               0          0            0                      0
...                  ...    ...        ...      ...       ...               ...              ...  ...        ...          ...        ...             ...        ...          ...                    ...
Country/Region  Thailand  Japan  Singapore    Nepal  Malaysia            Canada        Australia  ...   Djibouti  Gambia, The         US  United Kingdom       Guam  Puerto Rico  Republic of the Congo
Lat                   15     36     1.2833  28.1667       2.5           49.2827         -33.8688  ...    11.8251      13.4432    37.0902         16.7425    13.4443         18.2                  -1.44
Long                 101    138    103.833    84.25     112.5          -123.121          151.209  ...    42.5903     -15.3101   -95.7129        -62.1874    144.794        -66.5                 15.556
Status             Death  Death      Death    Death     Death             Death            Death  ...  Recovered    Recovered  Recovered       Recovered  Recovered    Recovered              Recovered
Date                Date   Date       Date     Date      Date              Date             Date  ...       Date         Date       Date            Date       Date         Date                   Date

[63 rows x 1425 columns]
```